# Rate of simple Rows

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find some rate for the following sum

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{\beta} \approx n^{??}$$  for $\beta > 0.5$

is it in general possible to find some rate according to $\beta$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\int\limits_{x=i-1}^{i} x^\beta\, dx  \le i^\beta \le \int\limits_{x=i}^{i+1} x^\beta\, dx$$

you can say  $$\int\limits_{x=0}^{n} x^\beta\, dx  \le \sum_{i=1}^n i^\beta \le \int\limits_{x=1}^{n+1} x^\beta\, dx$$

and so $$\tfrac1{\beta+1}n^{\beta+1} \le \sum_{i=1}^n i^\beta \le \tfrac1{\beta+1}(n+1)^{\beta+1} - \tfrac1{\beta+1}$$

and this is true for $\beta \ge 0$

Comment: great, thank you very much!

Comment: Do you maybe know some reference for this proof? @Henry

Comment: @GaußGirl20 No - but it is a basic technique.  A common application is to show $\log_e(n+1) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i \le 1+ \log_e(n)$

Comment: okay thank you!

Comment: is there also a similar result for $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^{-\beta}$ ??

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use your argument here?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900566/infinte-sums-inequalities-optimal-rate