# infinte sums, inequalities, optimal rate.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, infinity, sums-of-squares

Suppose we have a sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{2s}a_k^2<1\,\,\,\text{for some s > 1 }.
$$
I need to show for all $\gamma>1$ that
$$
\frac{\sum^n_{l=1}l^{\gamma}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-\gamma}a_k^2}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2}\lesssim n^2
$$
or find any sharper rate than $n^2$. So i need that $l^\gamma$ and $k^{-\gamma}$ somehow cancel each other out in some sense. Would you think this is possible? I would be glad for any suggestions or opinion!

Comment: I suggest trying to solve the continuous version first ($a_k \to a(x)$, sums $\to$ integrals). The factor in $l$ has a simple integral, and you can use some approximations that are more difficult in the discrete case. Once you find the continuous behavior, it should provide limits on the discrete behavior.